# Validation after database submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a payments model as follows:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :method, :payment_date, :reference_no, :invoice_id
  belongs_to :invoice

  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :method, presence: true
  validates :payment_date, presence: true
  validate  :payment_not_more_than_balance

  def payment_not_more_than_balance
     if amount > self.invoice.balance
     self.errors.add :amount, 'Payments should be less than or equal to the Invoice amount'
  end
 end
end
```

I am trying to run a validation whereby once someone attempts to make a payment that is greater than the invoice balance, a validation error is issued.

Currently, the code above makes a submission to the database then runs the validation.

That is to say if I have an invoice balance of 2000, when I make a payment of 2000, the payment is submitted (leaving me with an invoice balance of 0) and I am later issued with the error 'Payments should be less than or equal to the Invoice amount' which is not neccessary.

The error should run if I attempt to make another payment of 2000 when the Invoice balance is 0

How can i correct that?

Comment: you could make a before_validation hook. before_validation :your_validation

Comment: I did a before_validation hook and the problem still persisted, first saving and then running the validation

Comment: I think that a before_save is what you need, but make sure that it returns false to prevent from saving !

Answer (score 0):

use a before filter on your validation

```
before_save :payment_not_more_than_balance
```